# Can someone explain how になって works?

Tags: grammar, expressions

According to Jparser it means

to carry on shoulder

to bear (burden)

to shoulder (gun)

I'm not sure if this is correct or not

Can you give me a few sentences?

Also is this a conjugation form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a grammar form like に＋なって if that's what you're thinking.  It's simply the て-form of the verb [[担]{にな}う](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E6%8B%85%E3%81%86).